# Angular - get data over service between components

Tags: angular, service

I am pretty new with Angular and I will exchange data over service.
In the view of the receiving component I have the following html:

```
<app-timeconfirmation [institution] = "timeconfirmationafterchangeService.getInstitution()" [scheduleIntervalContainers] = "timeconfirmationafterchangeService.getScheduleContainers()"></app-timeconfirmation>
```

Is there a possibility in the receiving component to get the data not in der view but in the *.js component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a service and injected into those 2 components. something like:

**data.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  data: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
}
```

**component-one.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    ....
})
export class ComponentOneComponent {
    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
        dataService.data.next(...);
    }
}
```

**component-two.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    ....
})
export class ComponentTwoComponent {
    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
        dataService.data.subscribe(...);
    }
}
```